# Inserción de datos SQLServer y JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8.2

Si tengo en mi base de datos la clave primary(idEmpleado) en la primer columna como auto incrementable, como mando la inserción de datos mediante JAVA, ya que me esta tirando error.

Esta es mi capa de acceso a datos:

Capa de Datos

```
public class EmpleadoDAO
```

{
    private String mensaje="";

```
/*Pasamos los parametros de conexion y demas a los metodos*/
public String agregarEmpleado(Connection con, Empleado emp){
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Empleado (nombre, apellido, cedula, estadoCivil, genero, edad)"
            + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        /*pst recibe la conexion y preapara la SQL*/
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, emp.getNombre());
        pst.setString(2, emp.getApellido());
        pst.setString(3, emp.getCedula());
        pst.setString(4, emp.getEstadoCivil()+"");
        pst.setString(5, emp.getGenero()+"");
        pst.setInt(6, emp.getEdad());
        mensaje="Resgistro guardado";
        pst.execute();
        pst.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
       /*Mensaje de SQL*/ 
        mensaje="No se pudo guardar el mensaje \n"  + e.getMessage();
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

Clase con la que pruebo la inserción:

```
public class Test {
EmpleadoBO ebo = new EmpleadoBO();
Empleado emp = new Empleado();    
String mensaje = "" ;

public void insertar(){
    emp.setNombre("Daniel");
    emp.setApellido("Solis");
    emp.setCedula("al20120150");
    emp.setEstadoCivil('C');
    emp.setGenero('M');
    emp.setEdad(36);
    mensaje = ebo.agregarEmpleado(emp);
    System.out.println(mensaje);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.insertar();
}
```

Capa Negocio

```
public String agregarEmpleado(Empleado emp){
    Connection conn = Conexion.getConnection();
    try {
        mensaje = edao.agregarEmpleado(conn,emp);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        mensaje = mensaje + " " + e.getMessage();

    }finally{
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensaje = mensaje + " " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

No veo que este llamando algún método eliminar en mi test, cual pudiera ser el problema?

Gracias por la ayuda que se me pueda brindar.

DS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo debes eliminar la columna id del query

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Empleado (nombre, apellido, cedula, estadoCivil, genero, edad)"
            + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Si tienes bien configurado el campo en la base de datos para que sea autoincremental entonces se hará la inserción sin problemas.

Comment: He realizado la modificación que me mencionas, pero ahora corro el programa hago la inserción a la base de datos todo parece que funciono de maravilla, consulto la base de datos y no tengo ningún registro guardado.

Comment: Al parecer si me esta realizando la inserción en la base de datos, me di cuenta porque ejecuto el programa (7 veces ejecute el programa) fui a validar a SQLServer con una consulta select (no aparecen registros) pero si hago un INSERT INTO en SQL Server y luego otro Select * from, me devuelve el registro insertado pero el Id auto incrementable no aparece desde el numero 1 si no con el Id 8. Entonces si hace la inserción pero en que momento lo elimina? 
Ayuda por favor

Comment: Por lo que comentas parece que tienes activadas las transacciones, entonces se ejecuta el query y como no haces el commit de la transacción todo vuelve a como estaba menos la secuencia que no es manejada por la transacción, debes revisar cómo habilitar el autocommit de PreparedStatement o hacer el commit manualmente, intenta colocar pst.commit() luego del execute

Comment: Pense que el commit y roolback solo se usaban directamente en el manejador de base de datos.
Como puedo habilitar el autocommit que mencionas?
En que cual capa deberia de realizar esto?
@zerocool

Comment: Intenta eso que comenté a ver si es eso, colocar pst.commit(); luego de pst.execute(); aver si lo hace, Si es eso bueno buscamos como sería, sino entonces vemos qué mas puede ser

Comment: He agregado en la capa de negocio dentro del catch el rollback:
} catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            mensaje = mensaje + " " + e.getMessage();
            /*Podemos usar el Rollback y Commit*/
            conn.rollback();
        }finally{
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
En la capa de datos dentro del Try:
con.commit(); inmediatamente despues del Execute
Y de nuevo en el catch 
con.rollback

Funciono?
Si ya hizo la inserción, pero no si es correcta la forma en que lo he realizado.
Como active las transacciones?
@zerocool